# Does $ \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{n} - \ln(\frac{n+1}{n})) $ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the following series converges or diverges:
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n} - \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right) $$

I know that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} $ diverges and my intuition is that $\ln\frac{n+1}{n}$ doesnt effect it as it is going to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ so it still diverges but I'm not sure how to show it.

Thanks

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}-\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{2n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})$

Comment: the result is the Eulergamma constant

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310697/how-can-we-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-leftx-over-n-lnnx-over-n-right/2310703#2310703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Frullani's theorem
$$ \log\frac{n+1}{n}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}-e^{-(n+1)x}}{x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
and since $\frac{1}{n}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-nx}\,dx = \frac{1}{n}$, by the dominated convergence theorem we get
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\frac{n+1}{n}\right) &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}\right)\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-nx}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{e^x-1}\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{xe^x}\right)\,dx \tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the function $g(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}-\frac{1}{ze^z}$ is regular in a right neighbourhood of the origin and has an exponential decay as $z\to +\infty$, hence it belongs for sure to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$, implying that the original series is convergent. Additionally, the inequality
$$ \frac{1}{2}e^{-z}\leq \frac{1}{e^z-1}-\frac{1}{ze^z} \leq \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z}{12}\right)e^{-z} \tag{3}$$
implies that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\in \left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{12}\right].\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 3):

First note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^k(\frac{1}{n} -\log(n+1)+\log(n)))
=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n}-\log(k+1)
=\log k+\gamma+\epsilon_k-\log(k+1)
$$
since the series telescopes (where $\epsilon_k\to 0$ and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant). Finally
$$
\log k+\gamma+\epsilon_k-\log(k+1)=\log\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)+\gamma+\epsilon_k\to\gamma
$$
as $k\to \infty$ so that the series converges.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Use direct comparison test:

$$0<\frac1n-\ln\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)<\frac1{2n^2}$$

which follows from the Taylor expansion of the natural logarithm.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of partial sums:  $S_n = 1+\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3}+ \cdots+ \dfrac{1}{n}  - \ln n - \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) \to \gamma$ ( the Euler constant ) which is the value of the series.

Comment: I believe there is a typo with your partial sums.