# How can we show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({x\over n}-\ln{n+x\over n}\right)=x\gamma+\ln(x!)?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

A well-known Euler's series representing Euler-Mascheroni's constant

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[{1 \over n} -
\ln\left(n + 1 \over n\right)\right] = \gamma\label{1}\tag{1}
$$

The generalisation of \eqref{1} is:

> $$
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[{x \over n} -
> \ln\left(n + x\over n\right)\right] = x\gamma +\ln\left(x!\right)
> \label{2}\tag{2}
> $$

I have no idea how shows it; it was base on a guess and some numerical trial we conjecture \eqref{2}. **How can we prove \eqref{2} ?**.

Comment: Fun fact: Taylor expanding the logarithm gives a series of zeta functions.

Comment: You might be able to start from Weierstrass's definition of the Gamma function.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass.27s_definition

Comment: @BarryCipra That'd be quite short of an answer :P

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I'm not sure what you mean.  I've expanded my comment to a (very short!) answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We use the relationship between the Harmonic numbers and the digamma function:

$$\psi(x+1)+\gamma=H_x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n-\frac1{n+x}$$

Take the integral of both sides from $0$ to $x$ and you will find that

$$\ln(x!)+\gamma x=\ln(\Gamma(x+1))+\gamma x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac xn-\ln(n+x)+\ln(n)$$

> $$\ln(x!)+\gamma x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac xn-\ln\left(\frac{n+x}n\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

You may also use the well-known identity $$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n}}{n}\zeta\left(n\right)=\gamma x+\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right),\,-1<x\leq1$$ to find that $$\gamma x+\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right)=\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n}}{n}\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{1}{m^{n}}=\sum_{m\geq1}\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n}\frac{x^{n}}{m^{n}}$$ $$=\color{red}{\sum_{m\geq1}\left(-\log\left(1+\frac{x}{m}\right)+\frac{x}{m}\right)}.$$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{{x \over n} -
> \ln\pars{n + x\over n}} = x\gamma +\ln\pars{x!}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\left[{x \over n} - \ln\left(n + x \over n\right)\right] & = &
x\left[\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over n} - \ln\left(N\right)\right] +
\left[x\ln\left(N\right) + \ln\left(\prod_{n = 1}^{N}{n \over n + x}\right)\right]
\end{eqnarray}

---

The `product` $\ds{\prod}$ in the above expression  becomes:
\begin{align}
\prod_{n = 1}^{N}{n \over n + x} & =
{N! \over \pars{1 + x}^{\overline{N}}} =
{N! \over \Gamma\pars{1 + x + N}/\Gamma\pars{1 + x}} =
x!\,{N! \over \pars{N + x}!}
\\[5mm] &\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
x!\,{\root{2\pi}N^{N + 1/2}\expo{-N} \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{N + x}^{N + x +  1/2}\expo{-\pars{N + x}}} =
x!\,{N^{N + 1/2}\expo{x} \over
N^{N + x + 1/2}\,\pars{1 + x/N}^{N + x +  1/2}}
\\[5mm] &\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
x!\,N^{-x}\,{\expo{x} \over \pars{1 + x/N}^{N}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,x!\,N^{-x}
\end{align}

---

Finally,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\bracks{{x \over n} - \ln\pars{n + x \over n}} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
x\bracks{\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over n} - \ln\pars{N}} + \bracks{x\ln\pars{N} + \ln\pars{x!\,N^{-x}}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,
\bbx{x\gamma + \ln\pars{x!}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

The identity follows easily from [Weierstrass's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass.27s_definition) of the Gamma function:

$$\Gamma(x)={e^{-\gamma x}\over x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^{-1}e^{x/n}$$

Since $x!=x\Gamma(x)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
x\gamma+\ln(x!)
&=x\gamma+\ln(x\Gamma(x))\\
&=x\gamma+\ln x+\ln\Gamma(x)\\
&=x\gamma+\ln x-\gamma x-\ln x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[{x\over n}-\ln\left(1+{x\over n} \right)\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[{x\over n}-\ln\left(1+{x\over n} \right)\right]
\end{align}$$